# bash script + printf + how to indent the lies with printf

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have many files like the following ( the same concept on all the files )

```
 more list-OS23

 linux-d
 linux-01  fedora-linux-c
 Solaris_machine1
 AIX-65             linux-redhat18   unixware7-h  unix-digital
       linux56-a     linuxr9
```

my target is to indent the lines as the following format order

```
 more list-OS23


 cycel 1             cycel2             cycel3         cycel4


 linux-d
 linux-01...........fedora-linux-c 
 Solaris_machine1         
 AIX-65.............linux-redhat18.....unixware7-h....unix-igital              
 linux56-a .........linuxr9
```

can I get idea or real example how to indent the file?

I think printf is good command for this propose

Comment: How technical do you want to go?  Which language do you prefer to use?  There are tabulation libraries and format functions in many scripting languages.  Printf alone will not do it.

Comment: sorry - I update my question - see my example again

Comment: I prefer to do it with bash

Comment: Already asked twice on [SO]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142600/how-to-indent-the-lines-in-file-bash  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38145673/bash-script-printf-how-to-indent-the-lines-with-printf

Comment: this is diff format - please take a look on the stackoverflow quastion